# Printing an array in C with pointer

Tags: c, calculator

I am writing a calcutalor which takes multiple inputs. I seperated numbers and operations to 2 different arrays. But I can't print the arrays because I am not familier with pointers and it is giving me their position.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("You will enter your operations in number - operator order.\n");
    printf("How many numbers do you have to calculate?");
    int how_many; //how many numbers the user has in his/her whole operation
    scanf("%d",&how_many);
    int number_entry = how_many; //for example 1+2*9/5 has 4 numbers
    int operator_entry = how_many - 1; //and 3 operators
    int *number_in; //for every number as 1, 2 ,9 ,5 according to example
    char *operator_in; // and for every operator as +, * , / according to example
    int numbers[number_entry];
    int ops[operator_entry];
    int j;
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<operator_entry;j++){
        printf("Enter the number : ");
        scanf("%d",&number_in);
        numbers[j] = number_in;
        printf("Enter the operation as + for add, - for substract, * for multiply and / for division: ");
        scanf(" %c", &operator_in);
        ops[j] = operator_in;
    };
    printf("Enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d",&number_in); 
    numbers[number_entry+1] = number_in;
        
    
    int loop;

    for(loop = 0; loop < number_entry; loop++)
        printf("%d ", &numbers[loop]);
    
    for(loop = 0; loop < operator_entry; loop++)
        printf(" %c", ops[loop]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

'''

here you can see the output

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWVYY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your first printing loop should have

```
printf("%d ", numbers[loop]);
```

instead of

```
printf("%d ", &numbers[loop]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing the numbers and operators in different lines or the same? It seems like you are. If so then you need to add an escape sequence so they dont get printed in the same line.

```
    for(loop = 0; loop < number_entry; loop++)
        printf("%d ", numbers[loop]);
    puts("");
    for(loop = 0; loop < operator_entry; loop++)
        printf(" %c", ops[loop]);
```

`puts` is a function to print an unformatted string and also adds `"\n"` for you.